# Why doesn't this number input field accept comma's

Tags: html

I have an input field for an amount of money on my website, but this input field does not accept comma's. The problem is now that I can't type in an amount of dollars like $5,21. Please help... an example would be enough

```
Bedrag: <input type="number" name="goed_doel_bedrag" id="goed_doel_bedrag" step="any"min="0" placeholder="Vul hier het bedrag in">
```

Comment: It'll use the input locale of your browser to determine what characters are allowed.  Is your PC setup as US?

Comment: My pc is setup as Dutch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have:

```
input type="number"
```

This will restrict the control to accepting only floating point numbers. The following is from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

> **type**
>
> The type of control to display. The default type is text, if this
>   attribute is not specified. Possible values are:
>
> - `button:` A push button with no default behavior.
> - `checkbox:` A check box. You must use the value attribute to define the value submitted by this item. Use the checked attribute to
>     indicate whether this item is selected. You can also use the
>     indeterminate attribute to indicate that the checkbox is in an
>     indeterminate state (on most platforms, this draws a horizontal line
>     across the checkbox).
> - `color:` HTML5 A control for specifying a color. A color picker's UI has no required features other than accepting simple colors as text
>     (more info).
> - `date:` HTML5 A control for entering a date (year, month, and day, with no time).
> - `datetime:` HTML5 A control for entering a date and time (hour, minute, second, and fraction of a second) based on UTC time zone.
> - `datetime-local:` HTML5 A control for entering a date and time, with no time zone.
> - `email:` HTML5 A field for editing an e-mail address. The input value is validated to contain either the empty string or a single
>     valid e-mail address before submitting. The :valid and :invalid CSS
>     pseudo-classes are applied as appropriate.
> - `file:` A control that lets the user select a file. Use the accept attribute to define the types of files that the control can select.
> - `hidden:` A control that is not displayed, but whose value is submitted to the server.
> - `image:` A graphical submit button. You must use the src attribute to define the source of the image and the alt attribute to define
>     alternative text. You can use the height and width attributes to
>     define the size of the image in pixels.
> - `month:` HTML5 A control for entering a month and year, with no time zone.
> - `number:` HTML5 **A control for entering a floating point number.**
> - `password:` A single-line text field whose value is obscured. Use the maxlength attribute to specify the maximum length of the value
>     that can be entered.
> - `radio:` A radio button. You must use the value attribute to define the value submitted by this item. Use the checked attribute to
>     indicate whether this item is selected by default. Radio buttons that
>     have the same value for the name attribute are in the same "radio
>     button group"; only one radio button in a group can be selected at one
>     time.
> - `range:` HTML5 A control for entering a number whose exact value is not important. This type control uses the following default values if
>     the corresponding attributes are not specified: min: 0, max: 100,
>     value: min + (max-min)/2, or min if max is less than min, step: 1
> - `reset:` A button that resets the contents of the form to default values.
> - `search:` HTML5 A single-line text field for entering search strings; line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value.
> - `submit:` A button that submits the form.
> - `tel:` HTML5 A control for entering a telephone number; line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value, but no other syntax is
>     enforced. You can use attributes such as pattern and maxlength to
>     restrict values entered in the control. The :valid and :invalid CSS
>     pseudo-classes are applied as appropriate.
> - `text:` A single-line text field; line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value.
> - `time:` HTML5 A control for entering a time value with no time zone.
> - `url:` HTML5 A field for editing a URL. The input value is validated to contain either the empty string or a valid absolute URL before
>     submitting. Line-breaks and leading or trailing whitespace are
>     automatically removed from the input value. You can use attributes
>     such as pattern and maxlength to restrict values entered in the
>     control. The :valid and :invalid CSS pseudo-classes are applied as
>     appropriate.
> - `week:` HTML5 A control for entering a date consisting of a week-year number and a week number with no time zone.

Since it only accepts floats, it is not accepting input like `$123,456` (a string). Simply changing the input type to `text` will solve your problem.

You can also, prepend the control with your currency symbol, like [this example from bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms):

[image]

Comment: And probably cause a few others, like it accepting a, b & c.

Comment: Thanks I'll accept this answer in 7 minutes, need to wait... 

Credits to Burhan Khalid and DoctorMick

Comment: Can't i create a exception or something like that, to make it only accept numbers and comma even though it'sa text field

Comment: Yes @Anona, using for example regular expressions. Read more here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Use the following regex: `^[0-9]+[\\.\\,]{1}[0-9]+$`

Comment: The example in the question is in Dutch where it's custom to use the comma separator instead of the dot for decimals. In my (limited) testing adding `lang='nl'` to the field will accept numbers with a comma.