# How to add commas in a Input Number field?

Tags: angularjs, html

Simple question, but is getting me some problems.

I have a `<input type='number'>` and I want to show the input data with commas.For example, if the user types 1500, the field must show 1,500.

```
<input type="number" name="valuation_stocks" ng-model="valuation.estimated_stocks">
```

Comment: number does not support commas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this number input field accept comma's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702120/why-doesnt-this-number-input-field-accept-commas)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;


            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });


            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {

          elem.priceFormat({
            prefix: '',
            centsSeparator: ',',
            thousandsSeparator: '.'
        });                

                return elem[0].value;
            });
        }
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/741/

Comment: Also check this one http://plnkr.co/edit/T4MW49Rr3XDFjMW5gamL?p=preview